# Orthogonal functions

Tags: orthogonality, signal-processing

I am reading a paper about Non-coherent FSK modulation, we have **orthogonal functions** in that,  they have written

$$ \sin^2(\pi(a-b))/ \ (pi(a-b))^2  = 1 \ \ \ \ \ a=b $$
$$ \sin^2(\pi(a-b))/ \ (pi(a-b))^2  = 0 \ \ \ \ \ a!=b $$

Can anyone explain this how?

Isn't that a=b =0
and a!=b = some value ?

Comment: Perhaps $!=$ means $\neq$. Does that clear up your confusion?

Comment: @BenjaminWang Yes, Perhaps != means ≠.

Comment: @BenjaminWang let's say if a=a then it should be 0/0 is infinity 
We don't have limits here so it's not hopital rule. 
and if a ≠.b it gives a value, how a=b

Comment: Can you please link the paper?

Comment: https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?arnumber=380125&casa_token=MVO44-9u6joAAAAA:pxkYCu29ZlcI-au0zCaJ2u130vkdqOewIBuYYSZaJ6affy5do0ztFnsdSpFuH4c7chB8IENPtNA


equation -11 
page -3 
I hope you would gain excess. If not try this 


https://sci-hub.tw/https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C5&q=The+performance+of+noncoherent+orthogonal+M-FSK+in+the+presence+of+timing+and+frequency+errors&btnG=

Comment: here in actual equation a=i, but i don't mean an iota

Comment: Note that you actually copied the equation incorrectly in your question. (Also, in case you’re also confused about the $i=k$ case, (see my answer), this follows from $\sin(\pi \times \text{integer}) = 0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the linked paper and the equation number, you’re confused about this:

[image]

[image]

Edit:

The $i\neq k$ case follows from $\sin(\pi\times\text{integer}) = 0$.

Comment: Dear @Benjaman I appreciate your efforts however I told you earlier that this isn't hopital rule, one more thing how would you explain  i ≠.k =0

Comment: Sorry, I don’t know another way to explain it besides using L’Hospital.

Comment: Yes @Benjaman  sin(π×0)=0.
and  sin(π×integer)= some number and not zero.

Comment: Thankyou @Benjaman I appreciate all this. Thanks for helping the community.